# Mocking an array in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The following code should be creating an array and sending it along as part of the params hash:

```
        it "should create an outing" do 
            lambda do 
                post :create, { :outing => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:outing), :guestvalue => ["80","89"] , :barvalue => ["2976","2973"] }
            end.should change(Outing, :count).by(1)
        end
```

Instead, it's giving me the error:

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

The params are passed into this section of my controller:

```
    params[:guestvalue].each do |guest_id|
        @outing.add_guest(guest_id)
    end 

    params[:barvalue].each do |bar_id|
        @outing.add_bar(bar_id)
    end
```

Comment: please post where the params are passed into (You really should have just commented on your last post, no one likes a repeat post)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Still new here. Technically a different question, but I do see your point.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `lambda`, have you tried just using `do` without it?

Comment: I actually figured out it. The undefined method '[]' was coming from the next array, which I hadn't yet initialized. Dumb mistake. I honestly think it's about time to call it a day.

Comment: Please post an answer if you figured this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still interested, here's the proper syntax for passing an array:

```
post :create, { :outing => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:outing), :guestvalue => ["80","89"] , :barvalue => ["2976","2973"] }
```